# Pandas compare multiple columns against one column

Tags: pandas

I want to compare many columns in a dataframe against one column. Is there a non-loop way of doing this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9], 'd':[5,7,2]})
# works but requires one line per column
df['a'] = df['a'] < df['d']
df['b'] = df['b'] < df['d']
df['c'] = df['c'] < df['d']

# df[['a','b','c']] =  df[['a','b','c']] <  df[['d']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) with `axis=0` method, remove one `[]` from select `d` for select by `Series`:

```
df[['a','b','c']] =  df[['a','b','c']].lt(df['d'], axis=0)
print (df)
       a      b      c  d
0   True   True  False  5
1   True   True  False  7
2  False  False  False  2
```

Or you can compare by numpy array created from column `d`:

```
df[['a','b','c']] =  df[['a','b','c']] < df['d'].to_numpy()
print (df)
      a     b      c  d
0  True  True  False  5
1  True  True  False  7
2  True  True  False  2
```